# Importing product page titles and descriptions with csv into magento

Tags: importexport

Is there a way to import via a csv, product page titles and descriptions? we need to update this meta info for thousands of products and the developer says it cannot be done but we have to do manually.

obviously that will take alot of time.

does anyone know how to do this or know of a plug in that is reliable?

i found something for importing categories information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Magento already has a built in system for importing (create/update) products. Just go to `System->Import/Export->Import` and upload a csv file that looks like this:

```
sku, meta_title,           meta_description
SKU1,"Meta title for SKU1","Meta Description for SKU1"
```

Remove the spaces from the first line. I added them just to make it more readable.

Comment: sku, description is my csv columns names, but not woking, i get successfull message after import, right after cached and reindexed, description content  not in my products description box. actually i import description like table format :  http://i.imgur.com/NINxrOK.png

Answer (score 0):

[Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) is what you are looking for, I believe. It works better than magento's default import/export functionality but you will still need to generate a csv from your data source/feed.

Comment: Does magmi import bulk products description, if possible means what is the require columns names in csv.